# To select a Dynamic checkbox using it's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to select a checkbox using their default values. I have added the below code for the reference. My requirement is like if the server side value is 1 and default checkbox value is also 1 , the checkbox with value 1 should be selected without using the checkbox id.

Thanks in Advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title> new document </title>
  <meta name="generator" content="editplus" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
 </head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        //alert("clciked");
            $(":checkbox").each(function(){
                //alert($(this).val()); 
                if($(this).val()==1){       // assume 1 is a server side value
                $("input[type=checkbox]:contains('1')").attr("checked","checked");
                                /*var checkboxDefaultValue = $("#sampleDiv").find(":checkbox").val();
                                    alert(checkboxDefaultValue + "chkDefVal");
                                    if( checkboxDefaultValue==1){
                                    $("input:checkbox:contains('1')").attr("checked","checked");
                                } */  
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
 <body>
 <div id="sampleDiv">
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="1" class="sample" >1
<input type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="2" class = "sample" >2
<input type="checkbox" id="chk3" value="3" class = "sample" >3
</br>
</br>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value ="Show Values">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: checkbox values are coming from database, it's order might be changed , so it is not possible to use checkbox id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//Use $(this) instead of  $("input[type=checkbox]:contains('1')") :
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){

                $(":checkbox").each(function(){
                    if($(this).val()==1){     
                    $(this).attr("checked","checked");
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if($(this).val()==1){
    $(this).prop("checked",true);
}
```

Read more for `prop` http://api.jquery.com/prop

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get the checkbox with given value

```
$(':checkbox[value="' + 1 + '"]').prop('checked', true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's two ways to do it using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        //Only use one of the following:
        // this way will only select the first checkbox with the specified value
        $('input:checkbox[value="1"]').first().prop('checked', true);
        // this way will select all checkboxes with the specified value
        $('input:checkbox[value="1"]').prop('checked', true);
    });
});
</script>
```

I think this is probably the most efficient way to do it.